# Setting Culture / Language in RichTextBox WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, richtextbox, culture

Hi there is possible to set a default language or set a new one in RichTextBox, i want to set it in "es-PE" for spellchecker propouses

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem to be possible setting the [xml:lang](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx) as in the code below:

```
   <StackPanel>
    <RichTextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"/>
    <RichTextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" xml:lang="es-PE"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The first box checks in the default culture and the second in the specified one ("es-PE").

The documentation also suggests you could add this attribute to a parent control such as a panel and it will be inherited by the child controls.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the current thread's culture to the one you want? Most stuff in .NET takes the culture from the thread.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new Culture( "es-PE" );
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

Comment: This would effect all of the RichTextBox controls in the application