# difference between TextPointer in .net 3.5 and .net 4.0

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, .net-framework-version

I have a `WPF` project. There is a `RichTextBox` in one of my `Window`, My text(for example "`لَأَغْلِبَنَّ`") has some accented char(diacritics with char in arabic language).

the difference between `.net 3.5` and `.net 4.0`:

in `.net 4.0` => When I move caret right or left it doesn't stop on diacritics or when I press `delete` key it deletes char with diacritics on it, or when I call `GetNextInsertionPosition` with it, it jumps 2 for accented chars, but in `.net 3.5` it is not like this and everything is fine.

I have to use higher version of `.net 4.0` for my app and I need behavior of `RichTextBox` on `.net 3.5`.

Note : Behavior of `TextBox` and other `TextEditors` are like `RichTextBox`

can anyone suggest me how to solve it?

Comment: Are you running net 3.5 and 4.0 on same machine?  Are both using same Font?

Comment: yes, and same font

Comment: @Maryam: Seems like language related behavior. Try to specify the required language explicitly by using the `xml:lang`. See [https://stackoverflow.com/a/524343/6630084](https://stackoverflow.com/a/524343/6630084)